# Highslide: Issues re-shrinking image

Tags: javascript, highslide

First off, just want to thank the author for making this great bit of code available for free, and the community for helping java-illiterate folks such as myself.

Anywho, here is my issue: When I click a thumbnail to enlarge it, it enlarges just fine. However, when it's enlarged, the only way I can shrink it is by placing the cursor on the very thin ~1px border. I do not get the magnifying glass shrink cursor when over the image itself. If you wish to view the problem, the code is live at http://www.coloradocanopyclub.com/photos.html.

****EDIT TO ADD**** This issue seems to be affecting the first photo ONLY. (tallison.JPG)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The universal selector at the top of your style.css file causes this problem:
`* {margin:0px;padding:0px;top:0px;left: 0}`
It’s ok to set margin and padding to 0 for all elements, but the problem starts when you sets top/left position for all relative/absolute positioned elements 0.

You’ve probably noticed the Highslide full-expand button. This button is placed in an overlay on top of the image. Standard position for the full-expand button is bottom right corner: http://screencast.com/t/WPP4iwwCI9dq Your universal selector moves it to upper left corner: http://screencast.com/t/maXl9rzveH When the button is moved like this with CSS, it will result in an overlay that covers the entire image – colored red in this screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/6pdDnxaMRQ - which makes it impossible to close the image.

You need to change your universal selector to this:
`* {margin:0px;padding:0px;}`
And add `top:0px;left:0px;` only to the selectors where you need it, which are (as far as I can see) `#navlist li a span` and `#content`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you for not only helping me fix it, but explaining it in depth like that. That's a good bit of knowledge to have for future reference. Cheers!