# Highslide image expand issues with body margin set to 0px

Tags: css, highslide

Anyone know why the first image link wants to expands from the center of the page and not from center of the image when body margin is set to 0px? The second image always expands correctly from the center of the image no matter if set to 0px or not. Setting the margin to just 1px will force the first image to expand correctly.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/highslide/highslide.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/highslide/highslide-with-html.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="margin:0px;">
     <a class="highslide" href="/full.png" onclick="return hs.expand(this)"><img src="/thumb.png"></a>
     <a class="highslide" href="/full.png" onclick="return hs.expand(this)"><img src="/thumb.png"></a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This was similar but I still can't figure it out.
[Highslide: Issues re-shrinking image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306827/highslide-issues-re-shrinking-image)

As it turns out any image fails when directly next to body margin 0px.
Workaround is to place image or container 1px or more away.

Comment: Can you come up with a jsFiddle or CodePen for us to take a look at your CSS and HTML code? We can't do much but speculate without seeing something first.

Comment: Is it possible at either of those sites to sandbox the highslide project? I will look and see.

Comment: You can use **External Sources** tab in jsfiddle.net in order to add any external sources that are used by your site which means it can add the **highslide-with-html.js** and the **highslide.css**. All you have to do is to get the links to these files.

Comment: I have added a link in my original question.

Comment: BTW, if you want to see even more weirdness, set just the body margin-top or margin-left to zero. Oy!

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell you why it's happening, but if it doesn't louse up something else you're trying to do, one workaround is to wrap the thumbnails in a div and put at least a one-pixel margin on that div:

```
<body style="margin:0px;">
     <div style="margin:1px;">
          <a class="highslide" href="/full.png" onclick="return hs.expand(this)"><img src="/thumb.png"></a>
          <a class="highslide" href="/full.png" onclick="return hs.expand(this)"><img src="/thumb.png"></a>
     </div>
</body>
```